# Trying to Overwrite/Replace JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

In order to display a series of images, I am creating a brand new JPanel in my active listener method, and then sending that panel to another method to add the images. This works great, except when I hit "Search" again and need a whole new set of images. I get the new panel, but the old panel exists underneath it, so instead of New Panel replacing Old Panel, they just stack.

I tried assigning a blank panel to that spot at the very beginning of the active listener, but that doesn't seem to work. panel.removeAll() wouldn't work, as I'm creating a new imagesPanel each time. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

```
searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String searchString = searchText.getText();

            if (searchDropList.getSelectedItem().equals(character)) {


                ArrayList<Character> characterDetails = wikiDB.searchCharacter(searchString);

                if (characterDetails.size() == 0) {

                    //Do other stuff
                } else {

                    editCharacterButton.setVisible(true);

                    for (int i = 0; i < characterDetails.size(); i++) {
                        characterID = characterDetails.get(i).getCharacterID();

                    }

                    ArrayList<String> characterImages = wikiDB.searchImages(characterID);

                    JPanel imagesPanel = displayImages(characterImages, c);


                    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 6;

                    rootPanel.add(imagesPanel, c);
                    rootPanel.repaint();

                    setContentPane(rootPanel);
                    pack();
                    setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("Repainting.");

                }
            }
        }
    });

private JPanel displayImages(ArrayList<String> characterImages, GridBagConstraints c){
    BufferedImage img1 = null;
    JPanel imagesPanel = new JPanel();
    imagesPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    for (int x = 0; x < characterImages.size(); x++) {

        String imageURL = characterImages.get(x);

        try {
            URL url1 = new URL(imageURL);

            URLConnection conn1 = url1.openConnection();
            conn1.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
            InputStream in1 = conn1.getInputStream();

            img1 = ImageIO.read(in1);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (img1 != null) {

            //target size is no bigger than 100 x 100
            int w;
            int h;
            if (img1.getWidth() > img1.getHeight()) {
                //if the source was wider than it was tall, make the width 100,
                w = 100;
                //and scale the height accordingly
                h = (int) ((double) img1.getHeight() / img1.getWidth() * 100.0);
            } else {
                //otherwise, vice versa (and if w == h, then they are both 100)
                h = 100;
                int myH = img1.getHeight();
                int myW = img1.getWidth();
                w = (int) ((double) img1.getWidth() / img1.getHeight() * 100.0);

                w= w*3;
                h = h*3;
            }

            BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2 = img2.createGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, w, h, null);
            g2.dispose();

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = x%4;
            c.gridy = x/4;

            Border b1 = new BevelBorder(
                    BevelBorder.LOWERED, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.DARK_GRAY);
            Border b2 = new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 12);
            Border bTemp = new CompoundBorder(b1,b2);


            JLabel cIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img2));

            cIcon.setBorder(bTemp);
            imagesPanel.add(cIcon, c);

        }
    }

    return imagesPanel;

}
```

Comment: Did you tried rootPanel.removeAll()? or you also creat new rootPanel every time?

Comment: I don't create the rootPanel every time, just repaint it, but I do have several other objects tied to the rootPanel that don't change. Doing a rootPanel.removeAll would wipe those out, right? If I did a rootPanel.remove(imagesPanel), where could that go in my code?

Comment: I would try to make imagesPanel a class field, and remove it as you said, bu name. Then before imagesPanel = displayImages(characterImages, c); add rootPanel.remove(imagesPanel);.

Comment: You never tell it to remove the old panel... And to answer your other question, it could go anywhere before `repaint` (just note that you should also call revalidate to let the parent know that it needs to re-check it's layout)

Comment: Hmm when I make it a class field and try to do a rootPanel.remove(imagesPanel), followed by the imagesPanel = displayImages(characterImages, c), I get a nullPointerException error. Do I need to initiate the imagesPanel in the main constructor of the class (where I set the rootPanel to visible initially?)

Answer (score 2):

Create just one Panel and use the CardLayout [CardLayout tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

It is like a deck of cards. You can add cards by name, show the last one and delete cards, if it will be to many images.

For further information check here: [Cardlayout doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)